# Tweets Tutorial public timeline url dead public

Tags: qooxdoo

I am following the qooxdoo [tweets tutorial](http://www.qooxdoo.org/current/pages/desktop/tutorials/tutorial-part-1.html) and in the [part 3](http://www.qooxdoo.org/current/pages/desktop/tutorials/tutorial-part-3.html) it's seem the public timeline url is dead.

Is there another url or we can retrieve the data to perform the tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this location got lost when we migrated the website from 1&1 infrastructure, BUT you can find the respective file here ...

https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/blob/branch_5_0_x/component/tutorials/tweets/step4.5/source/resource/tweets/service.js

I will fix the tutorial.